# utf8mb4 in MySQL Workbench and JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench, utf8mb4

I've been working with a UTF-8 encoded MySQL DB that now needs to be able to store 4-byte emojis, so I decided to change from utf8 encoding to utf8mb4:

```
ALTER DATABASE bstdb CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE HISTORY CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE HISTORY CHANGE SOURCE_CONTEXT SOURCE_CONTEXT VARCHAR(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And changed mysql.conf.d "character-set-server = utf8" to "character-set-server = utf8mb4"

After these steps, I am able to store emojis (as ),but only when the SQL query is executed in the MySQL console: When I try to launch the query from MySQL Workbench or from a Wildfly webapp, I am getting this error:

> Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xA2' for column 'SOURCE_CONTEXT' at row 1

I assume I need to change the way the clients are connecting to the DB, but I have no clue on how. I've read something  on using "useUnicode=yes" in JDBC, but does not work.

> ${bdpath:3306/bstdb?useUnicode=yes}

*Edit*:
As suggested in comments, I tried with:

> ${bdpath:3306/bstdb?characterEncoding=UTF-8}

but no luck, I am getting the same "Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xA2'"  error.

Also tried

> ${bdpath:3306/bstdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8mb4&}

but it refuses to stablish a connection.

Any idea on how to configure MySQL workbench and/or JDBC/Wildfly?

MySQL version is 5.7.18

MySQL WorkBench version is 6.0.8

JDBC driver version is 5.1.34

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, it works. It was an issue with stored procedures, that was still utf8 instead of utf8mb4 after the migration.
It was a 2-steps  solution.

1. As suggested by @mike-adamenko set my.cnf to have the following

> [client]
>   default-character-set = utf8mb4
>
> [mysql]
>   default-character-set = utf8mb4
>
> [mysqld]
>   character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
>   character-set-server = utf8mb4
>   collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

2. Execute in mysql:

   > SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
3. Drop procedures involved, and create them again. They will be in utf8mb4.
   Can be checked with

> SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS where name LIKE 'procedure_name';

Comment: Missed that configuration file part in my answer, that's a learning for me!

Comment: what do you mean by "drop procedures involved" ? and for your 3rd point, can you give an example of what the `procedure_name` is? Getting empty results :(

Comment: By "procedures involved" I mean those that were custom-created in that given database, by using the "CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name etc etc" statement ("procedure_name" is the name you give to that procedure, as in a function name)

Answer (score 11):

Use `characterEncoding=utf8` for jdbc url

```
jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

Also check that you have configured MySQL to work with `utf8mb4`

```
    [client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

See [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)

Comment: The connection cannot be established at all when using the "characterEncoding=utf8mb4" parameter: : "java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'utf8mb4'."

Comment: You specify the Java encoding here, thus you should use `UTF-8`.

Comment: No, she doesn't need utf8 encoding

Comment: @MikeAdamenko "characterEncoding=utf8mb4" definitely doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Starting from MySQL Connector/J 5.1.47,

> When UTF-8 is used for characterEncoding in the connection string, it maps to the MySQL character set name utf8mb4.

You can check docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the documentation available for MySQL to resolve your problem. Here's the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html), that you could refer to.

Basically, your `ALTER TABLE` scripts can be changed as per the documentation mentioned above and then you could use the following parameter in your connection string for the changes to take effect.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourdatabasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Please don't forget to restart your MySQL services after making the character set and the encoding changes.

Comment: The connection cannot be established at all when using the "characterEncoding=utf8mb4" parameter: "java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'utf8mb4'."

Comment: You specify the Java encoding here, thus you should use `UTF-8`.

Comment: Nothing. The same issue as at the beginnging:  History: error in method 'create' : java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xA2' for column 'srcctxt' at row 1  :/